# How do you perform economic analysis of a country?

Tags: international-economics, national-income

I have no academic background in economics except for one class I took in engineering school. In this recent crisis of coronavirus, I would like to know how my country is doing overall and how deep in the water we are going to be in the future. What are parameters I should be looking at and how can I get a better understanding of the economic situation in my country. What would be best place to start the research? Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close because this is too broad to give any answer and it is also opinion based as from both economic and econometric perspective there are often multiple ways how to do different things. For example, do you want to analyze how corona virus affected growth? If so Short term or long term? Or do you care about inequality? Or impact on trade? Or maybe what really matters is unemployment? There are so many economic questions one can ask about effect of pandemic on economics you could make a carrier out it and how to examine all of the above would be context and also opinion dependent

Comment: @1muflon1 I want to know if my country will be able to function or not. If the country will have enough cash to run day to day operations. I am from a 3rd world country and we are totally dependent on remittance.   point me in an direction and I will take it from there. What ever you think will help me. I can read, I can do maths.

Comment: that’s still broad but if I understand, you don’t care about country but the government finances (since you talk about country having “enough cash to run day to day operations”). In that case you can look at literature on public finances and since you want to predict what will happen to it also forecasting. For the latter economic policy and forecasting from Carnot et al is a good source for the former you can look at public finance an international perspective by Greene although effects of pandemics were not extensively studied so far-that will require some wide literature search

Comment: You could read the business press, articles by the central bank, and supranational bodies like the IMF.